# examples for $f,g$ : $f \neq O(g) \land f \neq \Omega(g)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I am looking for further examples for two functions $f,g$ such that $f \neq O(g) \land f \neq \Omega(g)$.
I have found the old thread [Is there a function thats not in Big O and not in Big Omega?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040463/is-there-a-function-thats-not-in-big-o-and-not-in-big-omega) where this also discussed, however I wanted to know whether there are also more "basic" functions which fulfill this as opposed to functions with multiple exponentials and piecewise defined functions?

For example if I set $f=sin (x)$ and $g=x\cdot sin(x)²$ would this fulfill the above mentioned property?

Comment: Yes, $\sin x$ and $x\sin^2x$ are sound examples as $x\to\infty$. Some authors like to restrict the discussion to monotone functions, though, which is why the author of the answer you linked was stressing for increasing functions.

Comment: By the way, one answer mentions that $x\sin x\notin O(1)$ and $1\notin O(x\sin x)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Gae.S.: Thank you